# commandButton not visible in JSP File

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, weblogic

I have just been reading the similar post. I have corrected my mistakes. But not works...

I am programming with eclipse + weblogic.

I think that I have not explain too.

I need that works. Thanks.

index.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Videoclub</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
Index
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Ir a pagina 2" action="IndexToPagina2" ></h:commandButton>
<h:form>
nombre
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Ir a pagina 2" action="IndexToPagina2" ></h:commandButton>

</h:form>

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

pag2.jsp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:view>
pag2

</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Videoclub</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
        <message-bundle>resources.application</message-bundle>
        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
        </locale-config>
    </application>

    <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/index.jsp</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>IndexToPagina2</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/pag2.jsp</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

Comment: And how does the html received by the browser look?

Comment: I see only the word "Index", not the commandButton...

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandButton type="submit" value="Ir a pagina 2" action="IndexToPagina2" >
```

It seems you are using JSF. You need to import required taglibs.

Example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>
```

Read [more here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaph.html).

Comment: @user3474035: And you might be seeing some exception stack. Please refer that (or) update question with error.

Comment: The taglibs always are installed correctly. I am a Senior programmer, but I can't do that works... Maybe Weblogic need path system? I can't do that HelloWorld works...

Comment: @user3474035: Where are your tag lib files? Are they in lib folder of your project? I know for sure this is due to tag libs missing in classpath.

Comment: I have added taglibs when I have read your recommendation. But not works... The navigator give me 404 or 500 with "stackoverflow" error.